# Bot is remote but callback URL is localhost

Tags: azure, callback, bots, botframework, ngrok

I want to debug my azure bot with botframework emulator.
Whenever I try to connect, the emulator tells me the bot is remote but the callback URL is localhost.
How can I change this?
It also complains about my ngrok settings, but I am fairly sure that everything's allright about them, because I downloaded ngrok and pasted the correct path to the .exe in the settings.

How can I fix this problem?

[image: connecting to azure problems]

Note that I finally get an internal server error.
[image: internal Server error 500]

My Settings in the bot Framework page (as suggested by JustAShadow) are:

[image: Settings in botframework]

[image: further settings]

Comment: Probably you've configured your bot wrongly. Could you please check and share screenshot of "Settings" page of your bot in: https://dev.botframework.com/bots  
and bot app in: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the URL you entered in the box for URL on the emulator is supposed to be for local debugging.   I.E   you run your bot locally, get the URL for that local running bot, and add that localhost url to your bot emulator.    you are emulating an actual bot in a bot framework inside a bot framework emulator!

The emulator is built in order to emulate the Bot framework ENV, so that when you run your bot locally, it understands the type of environment you should be running under.

I.E   if you get DocumentDb emulator, you dont connect it to a real database, its just pretending to be azure, not Debugging Azure

Comment: Can you please give an example what the correct URL should look like? I am too stupid to understand your explaination yet.

Comment: not sure what you mean?  have you ran your bot locally yet?   if its running, its tells you where its running?  sounds like you still haven't tried running locally, in order to debug in the local bot emulator

Comment: When I run locally the bot emulator tells me it can't send. Which happens lately with all bots I created via the template provided by Visual Studio. In contrast when I download a bot application project from Github and let it run on localhost, the bot answers me something like "error. the message type is text/plain".

Comment: Windows phone emulator works nicely with the UWP templates or Xamarin template. It's just the bot template-apps; strange, isn't it? I think I'll try and download the template zips again into the Visual Studio template folder.

Comment: Problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Assure the MSID and PW are correct in the web.config when you publish

Comment: Yes they were. After many hours, I discovered that the Botframework emulator simply can't run properly behind a Proxy.

Comment: @7gegenTheben I'm Not sure how your issue was resolved since your last comment above says it was a Proxy issue but the response you have marked as an answer does not mention Proxy at all. Could you please explain? I've a similar issue that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378863/1232087) and am looking for a solution.

Comment: @nam I remember that I had to test outside of my company network because it's using a proxy for all web connections. I asked in the Botframwork emulator project on github why the debugging tool is unable to cope with proxys and was answered its an error. So, I went home, took my private laptop and my private WLAN and the I debugged using only localhost addresses in the botframework emulator field. You can do that by installing VS and download bot project as source code from azure. Select bot project in VS and click run, then start Emulator. upload changes to azure by VS publish section