# Microsoft Azure Bot Framework Emulator is not sending message

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-bot-service

On my Windows 10, I installed [Microsoft Azure Bot Framework Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) from the [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases) (I had used `botframework-emulator-setup-4.0.15-alpha.exe` from the GitHub link that Microsoft Article provided).

But when I run the Emulator, configure a bot and send a text message it says `couldn't send` (as highlighted in snapshot 3 below:

Step 1: Install Emulator
[image]
Step2: Create a new bot Configuration
[image]
Step3: Send message
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install ngrok tunneling. https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator/wiki/Tunneling-(ngrok)

Restart the emulator once installed.

Comment: I installed `ngrok tunneling` from the link you provided. Restarted `Emulator` but still the same exact problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: What was the error log showing on the right side panel of the emulator when you connect or send messages? Is it 401, 403 or 500.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct few things:

1. Change your messaging endpoint url to: `http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/api/messages` ; where **PORT_NUMBER** is the port number your app will be listening to. It should be specified in your code and ideally for most bot developers, it's value is either **3978** or **3979**
2. Check whether the **MSA app id** and **MSA app password** fields have any value in your code or not. If they have an ID-Password value present in your code then your emulator should also be configured with the same.

Comment: I'm not using any code (.NET etc.). I just created a bot in Azure tutorial using this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). And now I'm trying to test it in an Emulator using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) Azure tutorial.

Comment: @nam See any application you write must have some coding language written in the backend thorugh which it interacts with the cloud service (for your case Microsoft Azure which provides Platform-as-a-Service) / tools you are using. I can see your documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) where a section is there called **Bot Template** where it is clearly written that you need to choose either **C#** or **Node.js** . Try to read it thoroughly and try to understand the doc.