# Getting there was an error sending this message to your bot: http status code internalservererror

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, chatbot, web-chat

I have a C# bot project developed in Visual Studio which runs successfully on a bot emulator in desktop. This project was published to Azure. The same bot wouldn't work in web chat or in the "Test in Web Chat" window in Azure portal. It always replies with - couldn't send retry and showing there was an error sending this message to your bot: http status code internalservererror error message. Could someone please help me out.

Comment: Is the `Messaging endpoint` in the settings same with the one in the bot emulator?

Comment: In Bot emulator i tried with localhost URL in message endpoint added published URL

Comment: Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144699/there-was-an-error-sending-this-message-to-your-bot-test-in-web-chat) to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Joy. Now Bot is working in Azure  webchat but same endpoint URL not working in my Bot emulator got "The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies error message . Please help .my end point URL is https://chatbotXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/. I used this URL in emulator but not working

Comment: See if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423040/bot-is-remote-but-callback-url-is-localhost) helps.

Comment: am not sure about this example. i need to use only localhost URL in local Bot emulator? published URL not work in local Bot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181215/discussion-between-preethi-and-joy-wang).

Comment: May be this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/421#issuecomment-377553549) helps.